# Why is there a slip between strategic trading and drawing in Tradingview pine script?

Tags: pine-script

I'm writing a strategy in Tradingview.

When the backtest opens the position, the background color is set to green.

However, the test result and the background position are off by one bar.
Why don't the bar locations match?

This is a simple strategy that opens the position when the positive lines are continuous and closes when the negative lines appear.

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

var isOpenedLong = false

// if continuous positive line
longCondition = open[1] < close[1] and open < close
if (longCondition)
    isOpenedLong := true
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Open")

// if negative line
closeCondition = open < close
if (closeCondition)
    isOpenedLong := false
    strategy.close("Long", comment="Close")

// Change the background color when the position is open or already open
color currentColor = longCondition or isOpenedLong ? color.green : na
bgcolor(currentColor, transp=80)
```

The result looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)` with `strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true,process_orders_on_close = true)`